# how to restrict logged in user to see other URL in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to restrict user not to see others people data.
for example one user data is in this url

`http://example.com/abc/xyz/1`

i want to stop accessing

`http://example.com/abc/xyz/2`

I can stop it using normal php stuff but i want to know any thing in codeigniter that does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to handle this using your own code in the controller.

```
class Abc Extends CI_Controller {

    public function xyz($var) {
        if($var != some_condition_based_on_user)
            show_some_error();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it should be `class Abc` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the id of the user for example. When you log in you save the id of the user into session something like this in the model on login function:

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('user_id' => $user['id']);
```

after into your function you can check if the get value is the same of the session like:

```
public function xyz($id) {
        if($id != $this->session->userdata('user_id')){
           //code error
        }
}
```

Comment: i know that thing but i can not save many stuff in sessions and it is not an id.it could be product id as well